# how to test WCF JSON services - unit test

Tags: json, wcf, unit-testing

How can I test WCF JSON services. I want to create something like unit tests for this services. Is there any tutorial for something like this? I would b most interested to write the JSON object myself like
{somedata:abc,foo:boo}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link that might get you started.

http://www.entechsolutions.com/wcf-web-service-for-soap-json-and-xml-with-unit-tests

"-create a dynamic class that matches JSON datastructure
-Serialize it to JSON
-Send json to web service
-Deserilize response to a dynamic object
-Make sure that response has value that I expected"

POST

```
[Test]
public void Add_WhenMethodPost_And_ValidApiKey_ReturnsSum()
{
var addRequest = new
{
    Value1 = 5,
    Value2 = 11,
    ApiKey = Const.ValidApiKey
};

var url = string.Format("{0}/json/add", Const.WebServiceUrl);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonAddRequest = jsSerializer.Serialize(addRequest);

var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(jsonAddRequest);
writer.Close();

var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

string jsonString;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

var jsonAddResponse = jsSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);

Assert.AreEqual(16, jsonAddResponse["Sum"]);
}
```

GET

```
[Test]
public void Add_WhenMethodGet_And_ValidApiKey_ReturnsSum()
{
 var url = string.Format("{0}/json/add?value1={1}&amp;value2={2}&amp;apiKey={3}", Const.WebServiceUrl, 5, 11,
                         Const.ValidApiKey);
 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
 httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";

 string jsonString;
 var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

 using (var sr = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
 {
     jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();
 }

 var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var jsonAddResponse = jsSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);

 Assert.AreEqual(16, jsonAddResponse["Sum"]);
 }
```